# trigger controlID from user control page

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have the code below which looks like it should work.  However, the trigger that references the control with the controlID of "gvSearch" is actually a gridview inside a user control page.

How can I access that gridview so that I can use it as a trigger?

Thanks!

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlSearch" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" runat="server" >
      <Triggers>
          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearch" />
          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvSearch" />
      </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Thanks!

Outline:

```
<%@ Page Title="test">
<%@ Register src="test1.ascx" tagname="test1" tagprefix="test1uc" %>
    <UpdatePanel>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearch" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvSearch" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
             <test1uc:test1 ID="test1a" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What event do you want to use as trigger, the `SelectedIndexChanged`-event? Then apply the appropriate [`EventName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.eventname.aspx).

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvSearch" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

However, that should already be the [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaulteventattribute.aspx) event for `GridView` (see the [`remarks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.eventname.aspx) section).

Have a look at this thread: http://forums.asp.net/t/1136932.aspx

**Update** I think the best approach in your situation is to provide a custom event in your UserControl that is bubbled from the `SelectedIndexChanged` event from the `GridView` in the UC.  Then you can use this event as `AsyncPostBackTrigger` for your `UpdatePanel`, e.g.:

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="test1a" EventName="GridSearchClicked" />
```

Comment: but the control(gridview in this case) with the ControlID of "gvSearch" is inside a user control and I'm trying to figure out how to access it from my .aspx page - thanks

Comment: @999cm999: A common problem, have a look the the link i've provided last. In general it's not a good when different UserControls depend on each other, they don't work alone anymore.

Comment: in this case, the UpdatePanel in my page contains a gridview that exists in a user control.

Comment: @999cm999: The structure is yet  not really clear. Is the UserControl in the UpdatePanel? Give an outline of the layout.

Comment: Oh ok, I've updated my question to include an outline of my page.

Comment: @999cm999: Updated my answer. Do you need more assistance with the event or do you know how to create a custom event and raise it?

Comment: so I just create a custom event in the user control like: Public Event GridSearchClicked()?  Even though it's public, how will my page know where the event "GridSearchClicked" is?  -Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Setting aside the fact that requiring access to a subcontrol is not good practice, here's my best suggestion...

Create a `Public Sub` in your user control as follows:

```vb
Private ParentUpdatePanel As System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel

' Must be called on every Page_Load!
Public Sub RegisterAsyncTrigger(MyScriptManager As System.Web.UI.ScriptManager, MyUpdatePanel As System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel)
    MyScriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(gvSearch)
    ParentUpdatePanel = MyUpdatePanel
End Sub
```

On the Page_Load event, you'd call the function as follows:

```vb
Protected Sub Page_Load(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' Call our new function, passing in the current ScriptManager and the UpdatePanel
    ' The ScriptManager handles the asynchronous postbacks
    ' The UpdatePanel handles the dynamic updates
    test1.RegisterAsyncTrigger(ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me), pnlSearch)
End Sub
```

In the event handler inside the `gvSearch` GridView control which must update the panel would contain the following code:

```vb
ParentUpdatePanel.Update()
```